# Connecting Android Devices to Windows 7 via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, windows

I'm trying to connect both of my Android devices to my Windows 7 laptop, to see what I can do with them (file transfer, bluetooth tethering, etc.)

Here is the hardware I'm working with:

- Samsung Series 5 Laptop - Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 / fully patched

  - Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R) 3.0 + High Speed Adapter
  - Driver: Intel - 2011/12/09 - 1.0.90.20620
- Samsung Galaxy Nexus with Google official Android 4.1.1 Jelly Bean (*unrooted*)
- Asus / Google Nexus 7 with Google official Android 4.1.1 Jelly Bean (*unrooted*)

The pairing process between the Android devices and Windows 7 works flawlessly. Here is what I'm doing to pair them:

1. Put the Android device into discoverable mode (Settings --> Bluetooth --> Tap device name)
2. Open *Devices and Printers* on Windows 7
3. Click *Add Device*
4. Select Android device in device list and click *Next*
5. When the pairing code is displayed, confirm on Windows 7 and Android device
6. Pairing is complete

The devices are paired. However, they never seem to connect to each other. I see the device's icon switch between being greyed out and opaque, on Windows 7 *Devices and Printers* briefly, and eventually it just goes grey. No matter how much I tap on the Windows 7 computer's name in the list of paired devices on the Android device, it does not re-establish a connection.

One function that I tested successfully, is sending a file using **Bluetooth File Transfer** (*fsquirt.exe*). When I attempted to send a file to one of my Android devices, initiated from that utility on Windows, the Android device prompted me to accept the file transfer. The Bluetooth icon on Android was still greyed out, however, which indicates to me that the devices are not connected to each other persistently.

**Bottom line**: Does anyone know how to use Android Bluetooth features with Windows 7?

Comment: I too have never gotten this to work. I narrowed my troubles down to the Bluetooth stack (aka Bluetooth drivers) in Windows, couldn't find any that worked for me. What drivers are you using?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think once you have paired the devices, a constant Bluetooth connection is not kept and it is only used once you initiate an action i.e. file transfer. Once the action completes it goes back into standby / idle mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found Windows 7 Bluetooth lacking so I bought a third party package and have no problem using Windows 7 bluetooth with my Android devices.  The package was by Blue Soleil

Comment: Not a bad idea, but it seems crazy that I'd have to buy a Bluetooth stack for something I'd use so infrequently.

Comment: It's bad that android developers didn't deal with bluetooth implementation instead of all the fancy effects and clock that eats 10MB ram.

Answer (score 7):

I located a solution from this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZNPO1gMcoA and thought I would share here since this was the first result when I began looking for a solution.

The problem is that Windows does not detect the Bluetooth serial links automatically.  You can manually point to the standard windows drivers by completing the following steps.

1. Go to **Device Manager**
2. Right click the item under **Other Devices** labeled **Bluetooth Peripheral Device** and click **Update Driver Software**
3. Click **Browse my computer for...**
4. Click **Let me pick...**
5. Select **Ports (COM & LPT)** and click **Next**
6. Navigate to and select **Microsoft** in the left field, pick **Standard Serial over Bluetooth link** on the right field, and click **Next**
7. Click **OK** on the driver install warning box and it should successfully install the driver

I am unsure of why windows cannot automatically detect this component and install the driver, but this solution worked for me.  Hopefully it will for you as well.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is fsquirt.exe as a previous poster said. Not the nice auto pilot thing we would like, I know. I just used this for xfer of SS to win7 pc. 
Link:
http://plugable.com/2013/11/11/easy-way-to-use-bluetooth-to-exchange-files-with-your-phone-in-windows-fsquirt-guide/